# Can I sum values in a order by in JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing a Spring Boot App and I use JPA. My question is:

I have 3 fields (points1, points2 and points3) and I'm doing a ranking. So, I want to get the top of this ranking as a sum of these 3 fields.

Example to understand:

```
SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY u.totalPoints DESC;
Where u.totalPoints is the sum of points1, points2 and points3.
```

How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: those 3 fields are part of which entity?

Comment: Same entity, User

Comment: I need to translate the query (MySQL) to JPA: SELECT *, (`LEAGUE_POINTS` + `FORTNITE_POINTS` + `TFT_POINTS`) AS total_points FROM users ORDER BY total_points DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defined aliases for expressions in the `SELECT` clause, and utilize those aliases in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *, (points1 + points2 + points3) AS total_points 
FROM user 
ORDER BY total_points DESC
```

Comment: I tried it in MySQL and it works, but you know how can I do this in JPA?

Comment: @CarlosDevesa sorry no idea; but it should not be too difficult

Comment: Hey again, I got it. I change the EntityManager call createQuery to createNativeQuery and put default MySQL code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a correlated query here:

```
SELECT u FROM User u 
Where u.totalPoints = (select uu.points1 + uu.points2 + uu.points3 
                       from User uu 
                       where uu.id = u.id)
ORDER BY u.totalPoints DESC;
```

Comment: My field totalPoints isn't defined in the database, so I can't use. Can I create a temporal var for the sum?